# Rendering <UL> within <span> not happening correctly in <div>

Tags: css, html, jsp, dom

I have below div

```
   <DIV id=footerTop style="height:15%">    
        <DIV id=footerBottom>
            <DIV id=footerBottomLeft>
                    <DIV id=footerBottomRight>
                        <IMG alt=img src="images/images.jpg">
                    </DIV>
                    <SPAN>
                        <UL><%= new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(new java.util.Date()) %>blah blah!</UL>                                                       

                    </SPAN>
            </DIV>
        </DIV>
    </DIV>
```

Here span is not getting rendered properly in chrome and firefox. However in IE is working fine and  tag starts after some space within div. In chrome/firefox  gets printed without any space.

In the above code div containing span has following css setting which works fine in IE but not in chrome

```
#footerBottomLeft {
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; BACKGROUND: #FFFFFF; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; WIDTH: 100%; PADDING-TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 100%; TEXT-ALIGN: left
}
```

where text-align is to left with some space in IE but no space at all in chrome.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.  Comparative screenshots would help :)

Comment: "span is not getting rendered properly"? what does this mean? Since you are working with markup, show up some output. What exactly do you want as output?

Comment: The output i am expecting is the text within <UL> tag gets printed after some space within the table at left bottom of table/div where as in chrome and ff its totally left justified and no spaces at all

Comment: I have to question you're nesting of the <UL> within a <span>.  I would suggest changing the <span> to a <div> and applying styling to the div to improve the spacing. Usually the span tag is used for in-line elements per http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp. The <ul> is a block level element.

Comment: Also, the use of <UL> without <LI> is unusual, since the <UL> is supposed to apply to an unordered list of items.  If you're concerned about spacing, you should replace the UL tag with one that does not expect a list, such as a <div> or a <p> and apply styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I recommend to resolve the presented problem:

Styling:

```
<style>
#footerBottomLeft {
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; BACKGROUND: #FFFFFF; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; WIDTH: 100%; PADDING-TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 100%; TEXT-ALIGN: left;
}
p {
text-align:center;PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px;
}
</style>
```

The HTML:

```
<DIV id=footerTop style="height:15%">    
        <DIV id=footerBottom>
            <DIV id=footerBottomLeft>
                    <DIV id=footerBottomRight>
                        <IMG alt=img src="images/images.jpg">
                    </DIV>
                    <div>
                        <p ><%= new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(new java.util.Date()) %>blah blah!</p>                                                       

                    </div>
            </DIV>
        </DIV>
    </DIV>
```

On Google Chrome and MSIE it looks virtually the same, at the top and centered on the page. I acheive this by replacing <span> with a <div> and I replaced <UL> with a styled <P>.

Comment: My ul  tag also has some css UL {
 PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px
}  so the above code wont hold good

Comment: Okay I added the styling of your UL tag to the P tag.  Any better? It does look fine on my Google Chrome and MSIE.

Comment: If you could share your HTML and CSS at http://www.jsfiddle.net, I should be able to see better how I can help with the padding.

Answer (score 0):

According to W3C spec on [**HTML structure**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3):

> Generally, inline elements may contain **only data and other inline elements**.

As `UL` is not an inline element, inline element `SPAN` can't be its container. Also `UL` can only contain `LI` elements.

Comment: Would be useful if you cited something

Comment: @cxyz According to spec it's **not allowed**, so it's unreliable how browsers would render - even though some of them can meet your expectation, they still may behave differently, or even just throw errors. You should make your HTML valid first. By the way, `UL` can only contain `LI` elements, not plain text.